# link doesn't work after migrating wordpress website and changing URLs with plugin

Tags: database, wordpress, url, migrating

I tried to change the old URLs of my website to the new website URLs. The old domain was https://example.com/sophie (a subdomain) and the new domain was https://newexample.com (examples). However, I got a 500 internal error when I click links on the updated website. The homepage is working well. More information: I manually changed the sites URL in the database with:

/* MySQL: */
update wp_options set option_value = 'https://newexample.com' where option_name = 'siteurl';
update wp_options set option_value = 'https://newexample.com' where option_name = 'home';

and in wp-config with:
define('WP_HOME','https://newexample.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://newexample.com');

I cleared the cache of the server and the browser after adding those lines.

What went wrong? And how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure your new setup is using the same permalinks settings as your old website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that, you forgot to update the `.htaccess` file. Try editing that file and inside it, you might see something like this in the screenshot(sample):

[image]

Instead of the `wordpress`, yours might be `sophie`(the folder name). Just remove that word along with the trailing slash, and most probably it should work.

So, after removing that folder name, it would look something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That's the solution! It works. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @sophie96 Glad to know that you got it resolved! :)